# integration over dependent variables

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

given that $y = f(t)$ , does $$\int t\,dy = ty \text{ ??}$$

I don't think so, as $y$ is not independent of $t$. we can get $$dy = f'(t) \, dt $$ 
I see it's matter of constants here, but what about equations of non-symmetric sides, could we not care about constants? . For example, $$ \frac{dx}{ax} = \frac{dy}{(c-a) y} $$  $a$ , $c$, $x$, and $y$ are functions of $t$ .

does the solution equal to: $(c-a)\ln(x) = a \ln(y) + \ln(B) $ , $B$ is const.   ??

Comment: No, this isn't true in general. Using integration by parts, $$\int tdy = ty - \int y dt$$. In your example, what if $c(t) = x(t) + a$ for a constant $a$?

Comment: I didn't generate this example, even more, I don't expect the integration in my question to be true. I think it's not.
my example is a differential equation in a fluid dynamics problem and the solution I wrote is the answer, but I can't understand how it is true.

Comment: That would really depend on the form of $a$ and $c$ in relation to $x$ and $y$, right? I'm thinking this calls for a fresh question, with more context, like what precise differential equations you are using, etcetera. One way I could imagine this happening is if we were dealing with a partial differential equation of the form $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \frac{(c-a)y}{ax}$$ in which case $B$ would be a function of $a$ and $c$.

Comment: it's the Euler equations of streamlines of a fluid. it shows the total differentiation. the relation between $a$ and $c$ to $x$ and $y$ is neither given nor required.
when we solve this equation, we get an equation of surface, with another equation, the streamlines will be the curves of intersection.

Comment: I have next to zero experience with fluid mechanics, and limited in PDEs as well. I really think that you'll be more likely to have someone who can actually help you with this by posting a fresh question with all the details, given the age of the question, and that it currently seems to be asking something very different.

Comment: I wish I could do that, I will try to reform my question as possible as I can.
I appreciate your help :)